# How do you convert a collection to a Result in rust and actix to return data from postgres?

Tags: postgresql, rust, actix-web, tokio-postgres

Using rust and the actix framework, I am trying to fetch a list of records from postgres and return it as JSON.

I am referencing this example code: https://github.com/actix/examples/tree/master/databases/postgres

The following are my changes. The `get_users` function returns only one user because of the `pop`. How do I fix this to return the entire list of users so I can return it as JSON?

```rust
    pub async fn get_users(client: &Client) -> Result<User, MyError> {
        client
            .query("SELECT * FROM testing.users", &[])
            .await?
            .iter()
            .map(|row| User::from_row_ref(row).unwrap())
            .collect::<Vec<User>>()
            .pop()
            .ok_or(MyError::NotFound)
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pub async fn get_users(client: &Client) -> Result<Vec<User>, MyError> {
    let res = client
        .query("SELECT * FROM testing.users", &[])
        .await?
        .iter()
        .map(|row| User::from_row_ref(row).unwrap())
        .collect::<Vec<User>>();
    Ok(res)
}
```

We changed the return type from `Result<User, MyError>` to `Result<Vec<User>, MyError>`.

Let's follow what we changed in the function implementation. The result of `collect()` is `Vec<User>`.
In your piece of code, the `pop()` function returns an `Option`, which will be `None` if the vector is empty. In that case you convert the `None` to an error (via `ok_or()`).
Now the calls to `pop()` and `ok_or()` become redundant.
Since your function returns a `Result`, you need to *manually* wrap the `Vec<User>` that comes from `collect()` in a `Result::Ok` (remember, the `ok_or()` did that for you - in the case of `Some`, it would create a `Result::Ok`).